# Reading information about illegitimate children in Brackenhammer family, Kirchheim, Germany

Tags: germany, palaeography, baden-wuerttemberg, illegitimate

There was a lot of information about many different illegitimate children in family, however it is hard to read. Can anyone help?

The father had two wives, the first 10 kids are from his first wife, and the 11th kid is from his second wife I believe however he got him long before the first wife died!

[image: list of kids in the family]

There were so many illegitimate kids that the (priest?) had to continue writing info about them under the grandparent's names:

[image]

Comment: Not clear if you want a full transcript or focus on particular lines. Remarks (pending more complete answer): Sp. & spur. (latin) = illegimate. Child of 2nd marriage Paul Julius (illegimate per previous line) is noted as "Erkannt" (recognized, by his father). The 2 children at bottom of 1st image are grandchildren (mother is child #6). The 3 children on 2nd image are also grandchildren (mother is child #5)

Comment: I'd like a full transcript please (in German if possible if that is the language that is written - if Latin is used then I'd be screwed anyway so please translate it to English). I also believe illegitimate grandchildren and even great-grandchildren are mentioned but I do not understand the logic (if there is one). My great-great-grandmother was an (originally) illegitimate grandchildren of the family (legitimated later 6 monts after her birth) and she doesn't seem to be mentioned.

Comment: I think a full transcript, even in just one language, is too broad a question for this site.  I think you should crop out just the first part that you cannot read (a few lines or so) and focus your question on how to read that.  You can leave the whole image at the bottom for context.  Once you know how to read a few lines it may be that you can read a few more bits yourself and then come back with a new question to try and understand the next bit that you become stuck on.  Including your transcription so far would also be helpful.

Comment: There are lots of mistakes - If you want further details please contact my e-mail-adress

Comment: Dieter - welcome! Could you please add your corrections to the post? You can use the [edit] button below your post. I am sure Bregalad would appreciate any additional information you can help interpret

Comment: @DieterBrackenhammer - I reviewed your proposed edit to my answer and I applaud your work in addressing the deficiencies of my transcript. However, your link and table image should appear in your own answer. Bregalad may then switch the accepted answer marking to your answer -- and that's ok. [I'll wait 8 hours from the time of this comment to see either the new answer or another comment, before approving the edit]

Comment: @DieterBrackenhammer Hello Dieter, I added contact information in my profile specifically for this so we should be able to get in contact privately in order to exchange more details. Your extra informations compared to what I found before is amazing, but I wonder how you got all this.

Comment: @bgwiehle - You are right. My answer is situated at the wrong place. I'm little trained with this web page. I'm sorry. Therefore I would beg the administrator to remove my answer to a discrete part. Beyond that I'm only occasionally present to this page.

Comment: @DieterBrackenhammer - no need to apologize! Please create your answer (or you won't get credit for it), and I will roll back the changes to my answer. Your answer doesn't have to be exactly as before, if you want to make any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an improved family record of my ancestor August Hermann Friedrich Brackenhammer:

[image]

This is the familiy table of my ancestors of that time:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Unless a specific line needs to addressed further, the transcript is as complete as possible at this time. (Image unavoidable, tables not possible here). "?" where unsure. s/o = struck out

[image: Image 1 & 2 transcript]

Notes:

- conf. = confirmiert, confirmed; dates are mostly Sundays after Easter, named for the traditional text [1. Quasimodogeniti, 2. Misericordia, 3. Jubilate, 4. Cantate, 5. Rogate, 6. Exaudi]. Exception is Jud. = Judica, 5th Sunday in Lent
- cop. = copuliert, married
- right-hand column - no heading, prob. death date (but burial date possible)
- Sp. & spur.  = spurius, illegitimate
- s.u = siehe unten, see below
- ibid = same place
- g. = geb., geboren, nee/maiden name
- v. = von
- N. = Nummer, number
- n (or m) with straight line above = old handwriting convention for doubled letter (nn, mm)
- 1 with dot above = old handwriting convention to ensure 1 & 7 are distinguishable (esp if the writer uses a hook at the top for both)
- Erkert? - ink different from the preceeding "Paul Julius;" may have been added later. Originally I though this was "Erkannt" (recognized), but closer inspection casts doubt. Could be another middle name - eg. Erhard - but doesn't really match

Comment: 
This record is not one of the usual baptism, marriage and burial lists that churches are required to maintain. It is what is often called a "Familienbuch," a summary of the families in the parish, with the details culled from the "official" records. As such, it is extremely helpful in tying all the individuals together, often with information from other parishes, over 2 or 3 generations, but is subject to copy error. Because the illegimate children are not part of another (man's) household, they are included on their grandfather's pages.

Comment: I think you will need to stick to images of tables: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/please-add-support-for-tables-in-answers-and-questions

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks! Won't waste time trying -- will probably make the final version available on GoogleDrive if requested.

Comment: Just for info, Oskar Heftle was in "La Chaux de Fonds" :) (that's the only thing I know for sure about the family)

Comment: @bgwiehle This was really very helpful, however I am particularly interested in Herman and Helene (they were born here in Switzerland & my grandmother actually knew that Hermann). Is it possible that Helene is born in Laufen (BL), Switzerland ? When did she die, probably early, but there is two days and no year, that's very strange.